# Javascript alert not working after connecting to database

Tags: javascript, html, alert

In this problem I am trying to connect to database and get the output of a select query in a csv file. I tried different approaches but I caught up in same problem again and again. In the below code when I comment the line **conObj.Open(connectionString);** the alert works just fine. But when I uncomment the same it doesn't work. I am not understanding this behaviour. Kindly help.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" id='uname' name="uname" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id='psw' name="psw" required>
        <button type="submit" onclick="login(document.getElementById('uname').value,document.getElementById('psw').value)">Login</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function login(uname,pwd) {
        var conObj =new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection');
        var connectionString = "connection string (kind of private) ;"
        conObj.Open(connectionString);
        sql = "select dummy from dual";
        alert(sql);
        var a=3+2;
        alert(a);
        conObj.close;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Possibly because it causes a JavaScript error which stops the flow. Press F12 in the browser and have a look in the console

Comment: A `kind of private` connection string on the frontend isn't private any more. Use a server to connect to a database

Comment: Try putting the alert after connection is closed - I would assume it's because the db stuff is asynchronous.

Comment: Most likely that your connectionString is wrong and thus gives it an error so it won't continue.

Comment: I know using client side scripting to connect to the database is not secure, but I have environmental constraints (also the users of this code are internal people). And I don't think the connection string is wrong as there is another project which is using the same connection string. The existing project is running just fine. Kindly suggest if there is anything else I can try to make this work...

Comment: Also I tried putting the alerts after closing the connection. It is still not working. Kindly suggest if there is anything I can try to make this work.